# EXT JS 4.0.2a > Grid Filters > UI bugs

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid, extjs4

The filters plugin (feature in 4.0) is not showing right arrow icon in column menu.

also, StringFilter is not showing the find icon.

Also, the padding in string, range filter menu is odd.

All of these bugs exist in examples too
http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.2a/examples/grid-filtering/grid-filter-local.html

Did anyone find a solution for this?

Comment: They are sort of weird, but they are not part of the framework still (Ext.ux). I think best is just to hack it and diy one..

Answer (score -2):

You have to include additional css files from the ux folder. These two should be enough:

```
ext/examples/ux/grid/css/GridFilters.css
ext/examples/ux/grid/css/RangeMenu.css
```

Comment: this wont do. you could try.. the css files are in the example linked.